# How to move jar file in Maven Library

Tags: eclipse, maven, jar

[image]

[image]

I am using Eclipse Indigo with Maven. i have created `Maven Project` and selected `ArtifactId` as `webapp-archetype 1.5.1` as shown in the screen shot below.

When i am done completing the project, list of libraries appears under `Maven Library`. Now, i want to add few external `Jars` to `Maven Library` by going into its build-Path and add external jar, it adds the jar file but `NOT` under `Maven Library`. I can't manually move it under Maven Library, neither can i paste it.

P.S , i want to remove few jar files from the `Maven Library` as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add dependencies in your pom.xml not by adding external jars manually to your build path.

So remove the extra jar you added by hand end add:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
</dependency>
```

**Edit**

If you have m2eclipse plugin installed on your eclipse, right click on your project, and under Maven menu do a "Update project configuration".
Your new jar should be displayed under Maven dependencies

or if not, run a `mvn eclipse:clean eclipse:eclipse` to regenerate the `.project` and `.classpath` of your project

Comment: your procedure is correct BUT adding in the dependencies will `automatically` add it under `Maven Library`. `Automatically add` was the thing that i was looking for with the addition of ur code snippet ... however u have the +1 and correct answer :)

Comment: Another question, is there any other way to do the same task other then this procedure? I mean without editing .POM file and we do `something` and that something automatically adds the entry in the POM file?

Comment: You could do: Right clic on the project > Maven > Add dependency and you will have a wizard to enter group id, artifact id and version. Your pom will be updated accordingly.

Comment: When I run mvn eclipse:eclipse from a quickstart maven project, my eclipse build path appears a lot of duplicated dependency lib, like "M2_REPO/.../aa.jar". It seems that the jars appear twice in the "Maven dependency" and the root path. Why this happens?   I removed the M2_REPO entries.